# how to post collection list from client to server using restsharp in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, post, restsharp

Here i have code in Controller to send order detail or post it to server
Order contanis many property and one orderdetail list.
Order property is properly sent but the orderdetail collection list is not sent to the server
Client code:

```
    public static IRestResponse SaveYNOrder(Order order)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/OpManWeb.ServiceHost/api");

        var request = new RestRequest("SaveYNOrder", Method.POST);

        request.AddParameter("ID", order.ID);
        request.AddParameter("OrderNo", order.OrderNo);
        request.AddParameter("UserID", order.UserID);
        request.AddParameter("OrderedDate", order.OrderedDate);
        request.AddParameter("DeliveredDate", order.DeliveredDate);
        request.AddParameter("AddressID", order.AddressID);
        request.AddParameter("OrderRemarks", order.OrderRemarks);
        request.AddParameter("Discount", order.Discount);
        request.AddParameter("Shipping", order.Shipping);
        request.AddParameter("Tax", order.Tax);
        request.AddParameter("NetTotal", order.NetTotal);
        request.AddParameter("OrderStatus", order.OrderStatus);
        request.AddParameter("PayUsing", order.PayUsing);
        request.AddParameter("OrderDetails", order.OrderDetails);


        var response = client.Execute(request);

        return response;
    }
```

server code:

```
[Route("/SaveYNOrder/", Verbs = "POST")]

public class SaveYNOrder : IReturnVoid
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string OrderNo { get; set; }

    public string UserID { get; set; }

    public DateTime? OrderedDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DeliveredDate { get; set; }

    public int? AddressID { get; set; }

    public string OrderRemarks { get; set; }

    public double? Discount { get; set; }

    public double? Shipping { get; set; }

    public double? Tax { get; set; }

    public double NetTotal { get; set; }

    public int OrderStatus { get; set; }

    public int PayUsing { get; set; }

    public List<YNOrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }

}

public class YNOrderDetail
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int? OrderID { get; set; }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

}

    public void POST(SaveYNOrder request)
    {
        DbExec(dbConn =>
        {
        });
    }
```